# Excel Run-time error '13'

Tags: excel, vba

I use this VBA to lookup typing word in my database. if I type the word that is not in database, it will show disboard "Run-time error '13'"...help me dismiss it when I am typing new word

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=[C3], Address:="", SubAddress:= _
"EV!C" & Cells(3, 3)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always add `On Error Resume Next` at the top of your sub. In general I am not a fan of this construct (since errors should be handled rather than ignored), but a one-statement sub is a reasonable use-case for it. If an error is encountered, the sub will have no effect, which is what you seem to want. On the other hand, you could do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=[C3], Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "EV!C" & Cells(3, 3)
    End If
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid word."
End Sub
```

Comment: great! it's working. thank so much! ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤❤ ❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤❤

Comment: Glad I could help. You could always mark this answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem.